# How to make a new variable that assigns a numeric variable to intervals of 1000 units. R

Tags: r, intervals

In a dataframe I have the variable ***position*** that ranges from 0 to 2.7M.

I want to create a new variable ***bin*** that takes the value of ***position*** and it assigns it to intervals of 1000:

- From 1 to 1000 -> 1000
- From 1001 to 2000 -> 2000
- From 2001 to 3000 -> 3000
- etc

| position | bin |
| --- | --- |
| 128 | 1000 |
| 333 | 1000 |
| 2900 | 3000 |
| 4444 | 5000 |

I have looked at previous questions and couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
df$bin_2 <- (df$position %/% 1000 + 1) * 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cut`:

```
library(dplyr)

bin_size <- 1000
bin_seq <- seq(0, ceiling(max(df$position)/bin_size)*bin_size, bin_size)

df %>%
  mutate(bin = cut(
    position,
    bin_seq,
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    labels = bin_seq[-1]
  ))
```

**Output**

```
  position  bin
1      128 1000
2      333 1000
3     2900 3000
4     4444 5000
```

**Data**

```
df <-structure(list(position = c(128L, 333L, 2900L, 4444L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
bin <- 1000 * ceiling(position / 1000)
```